# Text in input appear somewhere else on page

Tags: javascript, html, input

How would I change this HTML5/JavaScript so it will change "Some text." to what you type rather then to "Hello World"

```
<p id="demo">Some text.</p>

<input type="text" size="20" onkeypress="myFunction()">

<script>
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello World";
}
</script>
```

Comment: Start by researching how to get the value from an `<input>`. See [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Answer (score 1):

```html
<p id="demo">Some text.</p>

<input type="text" size="20" onkeypress="myFunction(this)">

<script>
function myFunction(element) {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = element.value;
}
</script>
```

Have a read on [Input Attributes](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_text.asp) and see the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5v8tecgf/)

Comment: `onkeyup` is a better event since the demo text will be set to exactly what is in the input rather than everything except the last character